# How to access subclassed UIView's properties?

Tags: iphone

I'm having problem accessing the usual properties like frame, bounds, origin, size, etc etc. Within my subclassed UIView, I'm trying to edit the frame/bounds when the user presses something.

I keep getting this error 'frame' undeclared (first use in this function).

EyeView.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EyeView : UIView {
    CGFloat minWidth;
    CGFloat minHeight;
    bool touchInWindow, touchTopLeft, touchTop, touchTopRight, touchLeft, touchRight, touchBottomLeft, touchBottom, touchBottomRight;   
    bool dragging;
}

@property CGFloat minWidth;
@property CGFloat minHeight;

- (void)checkTouchedWhere:(NSSet *)touches;

@end
```

EyeView.m

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (touches.count == 1){
        if (dragging == TRUE){
                CGPoint prevPoint1 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] previousLocationInView:self];
                CGPoint currPoint1 = [[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0] locationInView:self];
            CGFloat differencex = currPoint1.x - prevPoint1.x;
            CGFloat differencey = currPoint1.y - prevPoint1.y;
            frame.origin.x += differencex;
            frame.origin.y += differencey;
            [self setNeedsDisplay];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you must share some code if you want answers.

Comment: Self.frame/self.view.frame doesn't work either..

Comment: Shows us the code in question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self.frame is working with Xcode 3.2.3 (remember is case-sensitive)

self.view doesn't exist in UIView (it exists in UIViewController), so self.view.frame won't work.

Try [self frame] instead.